# How would I make python look for a range in a file?

Tags: python

I am trying to make python open a file, and return all lines where `POINTBALANCE = <value>` is in the given range

```
num = input("Points to check: ")
num2 = num + str(100)

with open("glist.txt") as search:
    for line in search:
        if "POINTS BALANCE = " + num <= num <= num2 in line:
            print(line)
```

I want it to be so that if I input `100` in `num` that python automatically checks for `POINTSBALANCE -` with `100` to `200` and then when I put `200` in `num` i want it to check for `200` to `300`

Comment: As it seems "POINTS BALANCE = " + num <= num <= num2  will always yield a string. Can you post some sample lines from the file and also the desired output out of those sample lines for a given input?

Comment: First of all you are trying to use strings like numbers. str(100) is not a number but a text and if you try to add str(100) + str(100)  you will get "100100" and not 200. Secondly it is a little hard to understand what you want from your example so please show an input example with expected output. Thirdly If you want an answer post some example lines from your glist.txt. Otherwise people will not be able to really help you.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try extracting the number from the line (if `POINTSBALANCE =` exists) using a regular expression. Without example data it is bit of a guessing game and making assumptions, but for inspiration:

```
import re

num = int(input("Points to check: "))
delta = 100

pattern = 'POINTSBALANCE = (\d+)'
with open("glist.txt") as search:
    for line in search:
        regex = re.search(pattern, line)
        if regex and num <= int(regex.group(1)) <= num + delta:
            print(line)
```

Comment: Of course you can shoot with re on that problem - but do you think that this is the meaningful next step on the learning curve of someone who obviously is not completely aware of the concept of data types...? Not to mention that your re pattern isn't even explained in your answer.

Comment: I don't think we're to decide on the learning curve of popsmoke. Yes, he clearly should look into the concept of data types, but I think that was already made apparent in the comments to his question. My answer was merely meant as pointing him into a direction that he might look into next, hence the 'inspiration'.

Answer (score 0):

As already was pointed out in some comments you should cast integer strings to int to compare them with numbers.

Python's strings offer enough convenient functions to achieve your task here, namely

`str.startswith(substring)` - self explaining
`str.split()` - creating a list of substrings, by default split at spaces
`str.strip()` - remove unwanted characters at beginning and end

So your code could be changed to

```
num = int(input("Points to check: "))
num2 = num + 100

with open("glist.txt") as search:
    for line in search:
        if line.startswith("POINTS BALANCE = "):
            x = int(line.split('=')[-1].strip())
            if  (num <= x) and (x <= num2):
                print(line)
```